# How to curl at a specific port?

Tags: php, json, api, curl, port

I'm trying to receive a json string from a public [nxt](http://www.nxt.org/)-Node using php and curl. After some research I came across this solution:

```
$cURL = curl_init('http://23.94.134.161/nxt?requestType=getAccount&account=NXT-4VNQ-RWZC-4WWQ-GVM8S');
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_PORT, 7876);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

var_dump(curl_exec($cURL));
```

My output is always `bool(false)`.
I also tried changing the first line to

```
$cURL = curl_init('http://23.94.134.161:7876/nxt?requestType=getAccount&account=NXT-4VNQ-RWZC-4WWQ-GVM8S');
```

but it still returns nothing. What am I missing?

*When I use port 80 I get a 404 response as expected.*

Comment: Have you tried using `curl_error()` to retrieve the error? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: I just tried and don't have error. It retrieves me string(281) "{"unconfirmedBalanceNQT":"0","accountRS":"NXT-4VNQ-RWZC-4WWQ-GVM8S","name":"mystical","description":"","forgedBalanceNQT":"0","balanceNQT":"0","publicKey":"73080c6a224062660184f10ebb7fb431d459364a12403320c7f601f9d75cc547","requestProcessingTime":1,"account":"17013046603665206934"}"

Comment: Did you open the port to be able to go out of the server ?

Comment: @Julquas: I'm using a Shared Hosting Provider, where I don't have access to such settings. But I tried to use this script in all php playgrounds on google page 1 and it never works

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes: var_dump(curl_error()) prints NULL

Comment: @Paedow, I don't have errors too. It's likely that your Shared Hosting Provider is closed every port except for 80th.. Did you tried to run the script locally?